# Can we check the variable in IsNull tag in CamlQuery?

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query

```
var strName;

var query="<Query>"
      +"<Where>"
          +"<Or>"
            +"<IsNull>"
               + strName +            //Can this Works?
            "</IsNull>"
            +"<Eq>"
              +"<FieldRef Name='Name' />"
              +"<Value Type='Text'>"+strName+"</Value>"
            +"</Eq>"
          +"</Or>"
       +"</Where>"
    +"</Query>"
```

Comment: you can use it as `<IsNull><FieldRef Name='Name' /></IsNull>`

Answer (score 2):

No, you cant check variable in CAML query. In the condition, you need to specify the internal column name.

Your code should be as below:

```
var strName;

if(strName){
    var query="<Query></Query>";
}else{
    var query="<Query>"
      +"<Where>"
            +"<Eq>"
              +"<FieldRef Name='Name' />"
              +"<Value Type='Text'>"+strName+"</Value>"
            +"</Eq>"          
    +"</Query>"
}
```

Comment: So what can I do for it?
My Condition is : If the variable strName is null then I do not check the condition means <Where> , and if strName has some value then I want Where Condition in query.

Comment: check updated code